# Attribute sales to email campaigns based on time window

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Hopefully someone is able to help me with the following. I have two tables, one containing events which are "clicked emails" and one containing "conversions" (=orders). I would like to write attribution logic in BigQuery SQL to match the conversions to the clicked emails based on the following logic:

1. the matching ID is a "person_id"
2. conversions that happened within a 5 day (120h) timeframe after the clicked email count to that mail
3. if the customer clicked on two different emails within a five day window, the email clicked most recent before the conversion gets attributed the revenue

**To know:** the clicks table also contains clicks which do not have a conversion, and the conversions table also contains conversions not related to emails.

**Wished end result:** a table containing a count of all attributed orders and a count of all clicks, on date and campaign name.

I figured I would need to do a left join getting only the conversions in that might be related to a click, on person_id. However, now I need to define the window up until which conversions are counted (the 5 days). Maybe I could include this in the where statement? Then after that, I need to check, in case the count of conversions is > 1, to only take the conversion into account where the "date diff" is smallest.

How far I got :

```
SELECT
  c. person_id,
  c.campaign_name,
  c.datetime,
  s.processed_at,
  c.email,
  s.order_number,
  SUM(s.total_price) AS revenue,
  COUNT(DISTINCT s.order_number) AS orders
FROM
  `klaviyo_de_clicks` c
LEFT JOIN
  `klaviyo_de_conversions` s
ON
  c.person_id = s.person_id
GROUP BY
  1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you add an example of the data like `WITH data AS (SELECT [0,1,2] as id, [3,4,5] as value) SELECT * FROM data` and the expected output?

Comment: Or just add the sample data as *text tables* in the question.  It is really hard to follow and the description leaves open multiple possibliities.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the emails just before the conversion using `union all` and window functions.

The idea is to put all the data into a single "result set" with the clicks and conversions separated.  Then use window functions to get the previous click information for each conversion.

Your sample code as a bunch of columns not alluded to in your question.  But this is the structure of the code:

```
with cc as (
      select person_id, date_time, conversion_id, null as click_id
      from conversions c
      union all
      select person_id, date_time, null, click_id
      from clicks c
     )
select cc.*,
       (click_date_time >= datetime_add(datetime, interval -5 day)) as is_click_conversion
from (select cc.*,
             max(case when click_id is not null then date_time end) over (partition by person_id order by date_time) as click_date_time,
             last_value(click_id ignore nulls) over (partition by person_id order by date_time) as prev_click_id
      from cc
     ) cc
where conversion_id is not null;
```

If you need additional columns, you can use `join` to bring them in.